# SQL for fetching all date/times on a single date

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table of whose rows contain a date/time filled with appointment times.  The appointment times are a single field (i.e. the date and the time together).   I've created a recordset to fetch all the appointments which occur on a given date:

```
Dim dt as date

dt = #3/2/2019#

Set rs = Currentdb.OpenRecordSet("SELECT stuff FROM Appt WHERE 
Int(Appt.apptTime) = #" & dt & "#") --------
```

This works, but the "Int" function makes it inefficient.  One solution would be to separate the date/time field into two fields (date and time) then just search on the date field.  Unfortunately, I don't have the option of modifying the database structure.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can make this fetch more efficient?

Comment: use format on both sides instead?

Answer (score 1):

You must format the date expressions properly and remember the equal option:

```vb
Set rs = Currentdb.OpenRecordSet("SELECT stuff FROM Appt WHERE Appt.apptTime >= #" & Format(dt, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND Appt.apptTime < #" & Format(DateAdd("d", 1, dt), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a solution:

WHERE  (Appt.apptTime > #" & dt & "#)   AND   (Appt.apptTime < #" & dt + 1 & "#")

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateValue(Appt.apptTime)

eg:

```
"WHERE ( DateVaue(Appt.apptTime) = #" & dt & "#"
```

The above will return only the date part and remove the time portion.

However, the above can't use high-speed indexing. So, your follow answer of :

```
WHERE (Appt.apptTime > #" & dt & "#) AND (Appt.apptTime < #" & dt + 1 & "#")
```

will run much faster. The only other issue is that you should (need) to force the format to USA format, else your posted solution can fail depending on the users reginal (date format) settings. So, on some computer you find the above will not work, or fail, or even get things like 4/5/2020 mixed up. Is that April 5, or May 4th?

So, you need to correctly format the date to USA and ensure that you IGNORE the users date format, else your code will fail on many computers with different date formats.

You should create a helper function for this, like this:

```
Public Function quDateT(dt As Date) As String

  ' return formatted date

  quDateT = "#" & Format(dt, "mm\/dd\/yyyy HH:NN:SS") & "#"


End Function
```

Then, your query becomes:

```
WHERE (Appt.apptTime > " & qudateT(dt) & ") AND (attt.apptTime < " & qudateT(dt + 1)
```

Now in your case, DT will not have time, so the time portion of qudateT will be 00:00:00.

So, your example follow up should work, but you want to FORCE the date format to MM/DD/YYYY (USA) format, and if users have their setting such as DD/MM/YYYY, then your example query will fail on computers with such (different) regional settings.

Comment: I don't see why date formatting matter as all dates, regardless of displayed format, are stored as double-precision, floating-point numbers.  The integer portion being the number of days since December 30, 1899; the fractional portion being the fraction of the 24-hour day.  So my computation, which treats the dates as numbers should be immune to whatever date format has been chosen for the display of dates, right?

Comment: WHEN building a sql string, then it DOES matter. Using a direct expression like forms!frmName!Column name in the sql, then no problem. The INSTANT you start to create a where clause with a built up string, then that string takes on regional settings. The instant you do this, then that is the same instant you writing code dependent on the computers regional settings. Thus regional settings anything but MM/DD/YYYY, then your code will start to fail. So a direct forms! expression is ok, but any kind of string concat will cast date to string and that results in reginal format - not usa format.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see why date formatting matter as all dates, regardless of displayed format, are stored as double-precision, floating-point numbers. The integer portion being the number of days since December 30, 1899; the fractional portion being the fraction of the 24-hour day. So my computation (in my updated "found a solution" post), which treats the dates as numbers should be immune to whatever date format has been chosen for the display of dates, right?

Comment: do this in the debug window: ? "(" & date() & ")" and see what you get. The resulting expression is  of type string. Thus for a where clause you need:  "#" & date() & "#". That again results in a string. The converting of a var say "dt" or even using date(), or now() will spit out a string - and it will be spit out based on your reginal settings. As a result, you are not dealing with a internal date format, but a external representation of the date as a string. And as noted, the string will be spit out based on your reginal settings, but that string MUST be formatted as USA format.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I thought that, in that context, the hash marks only satisfied the compiler's type checking.  To treat the dates as numbers, I should have entered:
==========
    Dim dx as long
=============
    dx = Fix(CDbl(dtEntered))
==========
    ... WHERE  (Appt.apptTime > " & dx & ") AND (Appt.apptTime < " & dx + 1 & ")
==============
I believe this would work in all occasions, right?

Comment: Well, it should work, but controls on a form take on the ACTUAL datatype you set. So if you set a control as number (for format), then it returns a type of number. If you set a control as formated to date, then it returns a actual internal date() type value. And if the control is bound, then it returns the actual data type of the bound column type.  I can't say introducing a two type casting (fix + cdbl) is any better then treating the value as a true date type. It still better to keep and assume the actual data type then attempting to cast and change the data type.

Comment: as noted, if you use a forms! expresison (and I advoid them), then you get a true date type. and if you using recordset code, then again you are free to assign the value(s) directly recordset without conversion. However, I would not do all that casting when building the string. I mean, you can cast the date to a double, but you still inserting the double as now having been converted into that sql string (everything in that sql is a string if you are building up the sql). So, why cast from date->double->fix->string.  Why not go from date->string.